# TFS Build Process Never Completing

Tags: tfs

My TFS build setup can't seem to correctly complete a workflow.  Regardless of whether all the build steps actually run fine or fail, the workflow is always left in a running state (a blue play button in `Team Explorer - Builds`, rather than a green tick or a red cross).  It just hangs at the end it seems.

**TFS Setup**

- TFS application server is on server A with the build controller, Win 2008 R2, TFS 2012 Update 2
- Build agent is on a separate server B, Win 2008 R2, TFS 2012 Update 3

I've tried it for various build definitions, restarted the TFS service and the build agent, but the builds still always stay in a running state.

The only error I get in `Event Viewer -> TFS Operational Log` on the Build Agent machine is when I do a manual cancel of the workflow from Visual Studio.

> Default Agent - build: Cancelled the workflow instance for build vstfs://... with ID {...}
>
> Exception Type: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.BuildProcessTerminatationException

Everything else before that is fine.  Any ideas as to why the builds are never finishing?

Comment: Have you tried this against a different build agent, say of Update2 itself? Can you take a peek at the logs to see where in the workflow is the hang happening?

Comment: Thanks for the tips - I seem to have got it working now - I think it was just a network configuration issue.  As far as I can tell, Server B could not correctly see Server A, so perhaps wasn't able to tell the build controller that the build had completed?  I'm not sure if that makes sense, as they seemed to be able to communicate on other matters.  Secondly, I did create a new build agent on Server B - maybe this helped.  I'll if I can pin it down to make things more useful if someone else has a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

BuildProcessTerminatationException is activity of termination, occurs when you have an error.

I suggest you to debug your `sequential workflow foundation`, you have bug on your activity.

Open your template in visual studio, `set breakpoint on your first activity`.

`Attach process` of your host workflow foundation,  Build Agent and run a build.